# Django page not found, ajax request not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

Trying to send an ajax request to a django server and get a response containing some random data.

The homepage works, but the ajax request gives a 404 error as follows:

```
Using the URLconf defined in bms_project.urls,
Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^headstation/
^admin/

 The current path, chart_data/, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have <code>DEBUG = True</code> in
your Django settings file. Change that to <code>False</code>, and Django
will display a standard 404 page.
```

The url pattern is listen in a urls.py file inside the "headstation directory, then included by the normal urls.py script. It works for the home page:

project urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^headstation/', include('headstation.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

headstation urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^chart_data/$', views.chart_data, name='chart_data')
]
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
# get context of request from client
context = RequestContext(request)
# construct dictionary to pass template + context
context_dict = {'buildingName': 'The Building',
                'boldmessage': 'Put a message here'}

#render and return to client
return render_to_response('headstation/home.html', context_dict, context)

def chart_data(request):

if (request.method == 'POST'):
    dataX = [0,10,20,30,40,50,60]
    dataY = [25.0,24.2,25,24.0,24.5,25.1,25.5]

    response = {"x": dataX,
                "y": dataY}

return JsonResponse(response)
```

and finally, home.html where the ajax request is coming from:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
    <title>Homepage</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <h1>{{ buildingName }}</h1>
    Hello, message: <strong>{{ boldmessage }}</strong><br />
    <a href="/another-page/">Link to another page</a><br />

    <h1>Chart</h1>

    <script>
        var timeArray = [0,10,20,30,40,50,60];
        var dataArray = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

        $.ajax({
            url: '/chart_data/',
            type:"POST",
            data: {
                'data': 'temperature'
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    timeArray = data.x;
                    dataArray = data.y;
                    alert("recieved");
                }
            }
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: i think the url should be `url: 'headstation/chart_data/',`

Comment: Just tried that - The current path, <code>headstation/headstation/chart_data/</code>, didn't match any of these. Same error!

Comment: Have you tried `chart_data/` without the leading `/` ?

Comment: Yes, no luck either...

Comment: Ah interestingly the error is now about csrf tokens!

Comment: @csrf_exempt and it is fixed

Comment: if this can help, about setting up [csrf in ajax](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/#ajax)

Comment: excellent, I'll have a read

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the trailing slash before the `$` in your url regex or use a `?` before the $.

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^chart_data$', views.chart_data, name='chart_data')
]
```

You can also refer it by name in templates as `{% url 'app:url_name' %}`
You'll also need to pass csrf token along with your post data.

```
{% csrf_token %}
<script>
    var timeArray = [0,10,20,30,40,50,60];
    var dataArray = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

    $.ajax({
        var csrftoken = $('[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val();
        url: {% url 'headstation:chart_data' %},
        type:"POST",
        data: {
            'data': 'temperature',
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken,
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data) {
                timeArray = data.x;
                dataArray = data.y;
                alert("recieved");
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: placing the csrf_token there seems to cause an "unexpected "," error"

Comment: make sure you are not missing `,` after temperature

Comment: The comma is definitely there after temperature

Comment: @PhilS I have updated the code, Try using `{% csrf_token %}` above javascript (outside script code) which creates hidden csrf field for you. You can then get value by name.

Comment: From just adding in {% csrf_token %} the same unexpected comma

Comment: Is your javascript being loaded from elsewhere and your view is not directly calling this template?

Comment: Correct, the template was loaded earlier

Comment: If your view is not directly calling this template then you need to define csrftoken as global var in <script><script> in template being loaded by view. and then you can use that var in this JS code

Answer (score 0):

You can use '' (blank space) instead `^$`. It's working for me.

```py
url('^$', views.index, name='index'),
url('about/', views.about, name='about'),
```